# Css select first element after "header"

Tags: css

I want to select the first given element after the header element, how can I do this with CSS?

```
<header>
...
</header>

<div>Content</div>
```

the div after the header could also be a img or something like that..

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To select *any* element immediately following the `header` as a sibling you can use:

```
header + * {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just use something like this

```
header + div{

}

header + img{

}

header + section{

}
```

or

```
header + div,header + section,header + img{

    }
```

Comment: `>` is a child selector, so it would not match an element *after* another element. It would match an element *within* the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

If your first element will always be a `<div>` you could use Id or Class selectors.

```
</header>
<div id="first">...</div>
```

css:

```
#first {
    /* formatting */
}
```

More on [`id` and `class`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp)

If the next element is not always `<div>` you can use adjacent selectors. Adjacent selectors are selectors that match based on two tags appearing in the given order. Your first tag will always be `<header>` and the second is unknown.

```
header + * {
    /* formatting */
}
```

Here is an excellent table summarizing [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).